# What is a real life example of a Moore machine?

Tags: finite-automata

I have tried to find real life examples of [Moore machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine) because I have read a lot about Moore machines but I am still confused.

Are there any real life examples of a Moore machine? Any points I should know in order to understand Moore machines?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what questions are on topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elevator is a good example of a Moore machine. Imagine that each floor is a different state in the machine. Now, when you press a button to get to a certain level you change the actual state of the machine to the new level without giving any additional input. However, if we take a look at a residential security system, in order for an alarm to start, the system must be in the state of alertness and receiving an additional input generated from an intrusion.

Comment: A sewage lift station might display more of the independent looping behavior, where the elevator example requires human interaction. When the upper limit is triggered the pump turns on, then when the lower limit is triggered the pump turns off. The ladder logic utilized by SCADA systems might provide additional good examples.

Comment: But the elevator needs as an input the floor it needs to get, as well as its current state. so it looks like a mealy situation not a Moore

Answer (score 1):

An escalator in a shopping mall is an example of Moore machine. It doesn't need any input from the user. It will keep changing its state from the present floor to the next floor (the upward moving stairs that we see) and comes back to the present floor (which we can not see as they are hidden and sealed in a metal case).